# How do I extract paragraphs that start with a certain word from a txt file in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to selectively extract text from an interview transcript. I want to retain all the parts that start with "Interviewee:" and remove all the paragraphs that start with "Interviewer:".

I tried splitlines and define my own function but none of them worked:

```py
raw = open('Transcript.txt').read()

def select_text(text, paragraph_ending, keyword):
    paras = text.split(paragraph_ending)
    result = ''
    for para in paras:
        if para.startswith(keyword):
            x = para.replace(keyword, '')
            result += x
        return result

text_final = select_text(raw, '\n', 'Interviewee: ')
print(text_final)
```

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks all.

Comment: `text_final = "\n".join(s for s in raw.splitlines() if s.startswith("Interviewee:"))`

Comment: You should provide sample data with such questions. See [mcve].